# Swift Game Center Authentication

Tags: objective-c, xcode, swift, game-center

I'm having trouble authenticating in Game Center. I don't see whats the problem with my code.

```
func authenticateLocalPlayer(){
    var localPlayer = GKLocalPlayer()
    localPlayer.authenticateHandler = {(viewController, error) -> Void in
        if (viewController != nil) {
            self.presentViewController(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }else{
            println((GKLocalPlayer().authenticated))
        }
    }
}
```

And I call this function in side GameViewController

```
self.authenticateLocalPlayer()
```

every time I run the app I get a false return. I have the Settings>Game Center>Developer>SandBox>ON
 on my device but still I'm not able to authenticate inside my app.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Swift - Game Center not available](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25569028/swift-game-center-not-available)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question has to do with a bug in GKLocalPlayer() and Swift. Please see this very detailed answer that I gave from a few weeks ago:

[Swift - Game Center not available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25569028/swift-game-center-not-available/25593488#25593488)

Answer (score 0):

You can use that, I create a simple class for iOS game center in github
https://github.com/DaRkD0G/Easy-Game-Center-Swift

Message from France, Merry Christmas

Begin

**(1) Add FrameWork GameKit.framework**

**(2) Create two files :**

**GKLocalPlayerHack.h**

```
#import <GameKit/GameKit.h>
@interface GKLocalPlayerHack : NSObject
GKLocalPlayer *getLocalPlayer(void);
@end
```

**GKLocalPlayerHack.m**

```
#import "GKLocalPlayerHack.h"
@implementation GKLocalPlayerHack
GKLocalPlayer *getLocalPlayer(void) {
    return [GKLocalPlayer localPlayer];
}
@end
```

**(3) In your Swift Bridging Header.h (Objectic-c import)**

```
#import "GKLocalPlayerHack.h"
```

**Next**

```
class GameCenter {

// Game Center

let gameCenterPlayer=GKLocalPlayer.localPlayer()
var canUseGameCenter:Bool = false {
    didSet{if canUseGameCenter == true {// load prev. achievments form Game Center
        gameCenterLoadAchievements()}
    }}
var gameCenterAchievements=[String:GKAchievement]()

/**
    builder
*/
init(uiControlNow : UIViewController) {


    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    self.gameCenterPlayer.authenticateHandler={(var gameCenterVC:UIViewController!, var gameCenterError:NSError!) -> Void in

        if gameCenterVC != nil {
            //showAuthenticationDialogWhenReasonable: is an example method name. Create your own method that displays an authentication view when appropriate for your app.
            //showAuthenticationDialogWhenReasonable(gameCenterVC!)
            uiControlNow.presentViewController(gameCenterVC, animated: true, completion: { () -> Void in
                // no idea
            })
        }
        else if self.self.gameCenterPlayer.authenticated == true {
            self.self.canUseGameCenter = true
        } else  {
            self.canUseGameCenter = false
        }

        if gameCenterError != nil
        { println("Game Center error: \(gameCenterError)")}
    }


}


/**
    Load prev achievement granted to the player
*/
func gameCenterLoadAchievements(){
    // load all prev. achievements for GameCenter for the user to progress can be added
    var allAchievements=[GKAchievement]()

    GKAchievement.loadAchievementsWithCompletionHandler({ (allAchievements, error:NSError!) -> Void in
        if error != nil{
            println("Game Center: could not load achievements, error: \(error)")
        } else {
            for anAchievement in allAchievements  {
                if let oneAchievement = anAchievement as? GKAchievement {
                    self.gameCenterAchievements[oneAchievement.identifier]=oneAchievement}
            }
        }
    })
}


/**
    Add progress to an achievement

    :param: Progress achievement Double
    :param: ID Achievement
*/
func gameCenterAddProgressToAnAchievement(progress:Double,achievementID:String) {
    if canUseGameCenter == true { // only update progress if user opt-in to use Game Center
        // lookup if prev progress is logged for this achievement = achievement is already know (and loaded) form Game Center for this user
        var lookupAchievement:GKAchievement? = gameCenterAchievements[achievementID]

        if let achievement = lookupAchievement {
            // found the achievement with the given achievementID, check if it already 100% done
            if achievement.percentComplete != 100 {
                // set new progress
                achievement.percentComplete = progress
                if progress == 100.0  {achievement.showsCompletionBanner=true}  // show banner only if achievement is fully granted (progress is 100%)

                // try to report the progress to the Game Center
                GKAchievement.reportAchievements([achievement], withCompletionHandler:  {(var error:NSError!) -> Void in
                    if error != nil {
                        println("Couldn't save achievement (\(achievementID)) progress to \(progress) %")
                    }
                })
            }
            else {// achievemnt already granted, nothing to do
                println("DEBUG: Achievement (\(achievementID)) already granted")}
        } else { // never added  progress for this achievement, create achievement now, recall to add progress
            println("No achievement with ID (\(achievementID)) was found, no progress for this one was recoreded yet. Create achievement now.")
            gameCenterAchievements[achievementID] = GKAchievement(identifier: achievementID)
            // recursive recall this func now that the achievement exist
            gameCenterAddProgressToAnAchievement(progress, achievementID: achievementID)
        }
    }
}
/**
    Remove One Achievements

    :param: ID Achievement
*/
func resetAchievements(achievementID:String) {

    var lookupAchievement:GKAchievement? = gameCenterAchievements[achievementID]

    if let achievement = lookupAchievement {
        GKAchievement.resetAchievementsWithCompletionHandler({ (var error:NSError!) -> Void in
            if error != nil {
                ToolKit.log("Couldn't Reset achievement (\(achievementID))")
            } else {
                ToolKit.log("Reset achievement (\(achievementID))")
            }
        })

    } else {
        println("No achievement with ID (\(achievementID)) was found, no progress for this one was recoreded yet. Create achievement now.")

        gameCenterAchievements[achievementID] = GKAchievement(identifier: achievementID)
        // recursive recall this func now that the achievement exist
        self.resetAchievements(achievementID)
    }
}
```

}