# Game Center Unavailable Alert View not showing anymore?

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, game-center

In my previous SpriteKit games, when the player accesses the game center view controller, he/she is presented with an alert view saying `"Game Center Unavailable. Player is not signed in"` if he/she is not signed in to Game Center. This alert view shows even if I don't have it in my code. I think it is built-in.

Currently I am working on a new project but am using Swift and Xcode 6.1 this time (as opposed to Objective C and Xcode 6.0).

Now, I noticed that this alert does not show anymore when the player is not signed in when accessing the game center view controller. Did Apple remove it?  Do I have to manually code that now?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Swift - Game Center not available](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25569028/swift-game-center-not-available)

Comment: @c0dev Not a duplicate of that question. This question is asking about the lack of the alert.