# Game Center authentication doesn't work in iOS 8

Tags: ios, iphone, ios8, game-center

I am trying to implement Game Center in my game. I've tried it on the iOS 8 GM.
I'm not able to get the authentication to work on device, but it works fine in the simulator. I'm using the code provided in Apple's documentation.

Do other people have the same issue? Any advice?

Comment: Can you post the code you're using, or a link to it? What error message are you getting, if any?

Comment: it got this message : Domain=GKErrorDomain Code=15 "The requested operation could not be completed because this application is not recognized by Game Center." UserInfo=0x17d08ee0 {NSLocalizedDescription=The requested operation could not be completed because this application is not recognized by Game Center.}

Comment: Have you tried other solutions for that error? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24045244/game-center-not-authenticating-using-swift

Comment: this is not very help full in my case, because i use Objective-C. I checked the return and everything is fine in my code, and it works in the simulator.

Comment: Have you tried the second answer on the page I linked to? 'The solution (discovered through Apple's Dev forum) was to go to "Settings" on the device, and then into "Game Centre" and enable "Sandbox" under the developer section.'

Comment: Have you enabled Game Center in iTunes Connect?

Answer (score 98, accepted):

Happened to me as well in iOS8[image]. Just need to enable Sandbox in Settings--> Game Center --> Sandbox.

Comment: Why is this happening? Because is not signed with AppStore provision? I have a build signed with release provision (ad-hoc), Game Center is enabled in itunesconnect, the AppID I use has Game Center enabled for dev and release. Is it going to work without Sandbox if we release the game?

Comment: I don't have the `Sandbox` option box in this setting. Do you know why?

Comment: @jayatubi Sounds like you might be using the simulator? The simulator is always sandboxed.

Comment: I am using the iOS 9 beta. Maybe this is a developer preview version so the sandbox is also always enabled.

Answer (score 6):

In order to make it works you must be sure that:

1. The SandBox Mode it's Enable on your device
2. Your bundle id on Xcode must be the same bundle id on Itunes Connect
3. You have to enable the Game center on itunes connect:
   [image: Itunes Connect Game Center]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

1. Go to itunesconnect website  (https://itunesconnect.apple.com)
2. Open Your app. (in My apps section)
3. Find "Game Center" tab. Click it.
4. Then click on switch "Enable/Disabled"