# iOS Swift game with game center not working on signed app

Tags: ios, swift, game-center, gamekit, ios8.1

I submitted an iOS 8.1 Swift iPhone app for TestFlight beta testing as well as AppStore review. It is using Game Center and everything works fine IF we enable "Sandbox" mode on the phone. However, now it needs to work in production, and I keep getting error indicating that the App is not recognized by Game Center.

I am NOT using a beta version of any software. Opened a case with Apple as well, but wanted to ask SO users how they switched to production Game Center environments. Please help.

By the way I already tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24045244/game-center-not-authenticating-using-swift?lq=1) and other such ideas with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

I had generated the distribution cert on another Mac, and Xcode Archive did not automatically generate a new cert for me. Going to the iTunes Connect and generating a new cert fixed the issue for me.